# barbatus:star-rating error in meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor

i m making a webapp using meteor js template.I want to use star rating so i downloaded the barbatus star rating package and after downloading finished i used the html code `<p> 
            {{> starsRating id='rating' size='lg' mutable=true}}
        </p>`
but whwn i run using meteor command it give me an error :
 error: no plugin found for stars_rating.less in barbatus:stars-rating;
   a plugin for *.less was active when it was published but none is now
I dont know what goes wrong.plz help me

Answer (score 5):

As `barbatus:stars-rating` has a less dependency, 
run :

```
  **$** meteor update less

  **$** meteor
```

As soon as the less package is updated, `stars-rating` will work again.
Tested just a few minutes ago.